# Angularjs: How to get the amount of weeks between 2 dates?

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the amount of weeks that are in between 2 dates in a angular project.

I've tried this:

```
vakken.getWeken = function() {

    vakken.tijd = 0;
    vakken.weken = 0;

    var een_week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

    var d1ms = vakken.periodeind.getTime();
    var d2ms = vakken.periodstart.getTime();

    var verschilms = Math.abs(d1ms - d2ms);

    vakken.weken = Math.floor(verschilms / een_week);

    console.log(vakken.weken)
}
```

But i get this `typeError`, TypeError: vakken.periodeind.getTime is not a function.

call:

```
$http({
                        method: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/periode.php',
                        params: {
                            periodecode: periodecode,
                            callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
                        }
                    }).then(function succes(response)
                        {
                            if (response.data.state == "Failed") 
                            {
                                console.log(failed);
                            }

                            else {
                                console.log(response);
                                vakken.periodstart = response.data.periods[0].start.full;
                                vakken.periodeind = response.data.periods[0].eind.full;
                                //console.log(vakken.periode)
                                vakken.getWeken();
                            }
                        }
                    );
```

Comment: are you sure that periodeind is a Date? can you log that value to the console and see what it is?

Comment: How is `vakken` defined? Try a `console.log(vakken)` at the beginning of that function.

Comment: i have logged it and it gives a date

Comment: vakken is defined here: `controller: ["$http", "userValue", "studentService", function($http, user, service){
                vakken = this;`

Comment: I'm guessing those dates are coming back as strings. You would need to parse the string into a date object before being able to call getTime() on them. When you log them, what format are they coming back as? Check out the Date.parse() method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because those variables are not defined, you must pass those as a input parameter using an object or two different variables. if you take vaken which has `periodeind` and `peiodstart`

```
vakken.getWeken = function(vakken) {
    vakken.tijd = 0;
    vakken.weken = 0;
    var een_week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    var d1ms = vakken.periodeind.getTime();
    var d2ms = vakken.periodstart.getTime();
    var verschilms = Math.abs(d1ms - d2ms);
    vakken.weken = Math.floor(verschilms / een_week);
    console.log(vakken.weken)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Pass those two variables to the function,

```
 vakken.periodstart = response.data.periods[0].start.full;
 vakken.periodeind = response.data.periods[0].eind.full;
 vakken.getWeken(vakken.periodstart,vakken.periodeind);
```

and in Function

```
 vakken.getWeken = function(fromDate,ToDate) {
        vakken.tijd = 0;
        vakken.weken = 0;
        var een_week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
        var d1ms = fromDate.getTime();
        var d2ms = ToDate.getTime();
        var verschilms = Math.abs(d1ms - d2ms);
        vakken.weken = Math.floor(verschilms / een_week);
        console.log(vakken.weken)
    }
```

Comment: I think `vakken` must already be defined, because the function itself is a method of `vakken`...

Comment: @nnnnnn what i meant was he has mentioned no where those variables

Comment: the variables come from an api call. i will put this in the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the start and end dates are supposed to be properties on the same "vakken" that the method is defined on, you probably mean to do:

```
vakken.getWeken = function() {

    this.tijd = 0;
    this.weken = 0;

    var een_week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

    var d1ms = this.periodeind.getTime();
    var d2ms = this.periodstart.getTime();

    var verschilms = Math.abs(d1ms - d2ms);

    this.weken = Math.floor(verschilms / een_week);

    console.log(this.weken);
}
```

Comment: If it's the same `vakken`, why wouldn't it work to reference it as such from within the function? Using `this` is neater, but it shouldn't be *necessary* here.

Comment: I'd have to see how you define vakken and how you are creating one.

Comment: now that I see the code, it shouldn't really make a difference in this case, but see my comment on your original question. If you are return date strings, you will need to parse them into date objects before calling getTime()

Comment: Yes i think that was the problem to, but i ended up doing it in a totally different way

Answer (score -1):

Use [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/):

To get whole weeks:

`moment(last_date).diff(first_date, 'weeks')`

Or add `true` to get precise number in fractions of weeks:

`moment(last_date).diff(first_date, 'weeks', true)`